# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "posts" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to run a scraping task on my local machine that then creates a post in my production database (Heroku and PostgresSQL). For this I am using `rails scrape:scrapeWeb RAILS_ENV=production`.

Even though this used to work in the past, now I get thrown the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
```

The line that causes this is this one:
`Post.create(user_id: 1, link: link, to_be_checked: true)`, so it us just a simple Post creation.

Other interesting things:

- Reseting the database and trying to run all the migrations again did not help
- When I run the line `Post.create(user_id: 1, link: link, to_be_checked: true)` in my production console (via heroku run rails c), it creates the post perfectly without problems.
- Running the task locally on my development database works perfectly.
- I cannot run the task on my production server as it uses Kimurai, which doesnt work with heroku.

Thanks so much for any input!

Comment: I don't know anything about ruby, but this caught my eye:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass. Why is this query using double quotes " around the name posts ?

Comment: Did you run rails db:migrate? How do you connect to prod?

Comment: Having a similar issue... curious if you've recently upgraded to Rails 7?

Comment: @FrankHeikens when I looked at previous answers about this problem the solutions never involved fixing the double quotes, so I dont think its part of the problem (even if the solutions did not work for me)

Comment: I ran rails db:migrate multiple times and also resetted the complete db '
This is still rails 6, so I did not upgrade to Rails 7